# local notification buttons doesn't made any action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, notifications

With ionic 4, I'm using plugin localNotifications of:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

I want to implement 'yes', 'no' options and make an action only if the yes button is touched, and if the button no 'is' clicked, simply want to close the notification, I made this implementation in my real project, and the action buttons 'works', but that buttons only works fine when I'm in the app or if I have the app suspended but visible (the menu where you can kill the apps).

Here is the detail: if I touch the home button and try to select actions yes or no, if I select 'yes' the app is launched correctly (the yes button have a launch action), but if I attempt to click in the 'no' option, and the app is not visible for some reason the app got closed and doesn't appears in the menu where you can kill apps, (but when I open again the app, the app will be resumed where I was), a bit strange...

it's hard to debug that because when the app is not active console doesn't log anything (inspector console only works when app is active).

literally I'm having this issue for hours, so I tried to make a new project only for tests with this plugin, and in the new project the buttons don't close the app if previously I made a click in home button, but got a new problem: the actions don't be fired...

I already attempt to use background mode and activate it in the new project, but this doesn't make any difference, other thing that I tried is to put my on (events), in the deviceready function:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', ()=>{

      this.isAcceptedObservable = this.localNotifications.on('yes').subscribe(res =>{

        console.log('confirmed!');

      });

      this.isNotAcceptedObservable = this.localNotifications.on('no').subscribe(res =>{

        console.log('denied!');

      });

    });
```

But nothing happened...

also I tried to quit foreground option in schedule options, but this doesn't make any difference...

here is my code for testing, app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NgPipesModule } from 'ngx-pipes';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, NgPipesModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    LocalNotifications,
    BackgroundMode,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.page.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-button expand = "full" (click) = "showNotification()">
    <ion-label>
      Show notification...
    </ion-label>
  </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

home.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import {NgPipesModule} from 'ngx-pipes';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    NgPipesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
  providers: [LocalNotifications]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

home.page.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications/ngx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {

  public isAcceptedObservable: Subscription;
  public isNotAcceptedObservable: Subscription;

  constructor(private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode){

    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', ()=>{

      this.isAcceptedObservable = this.localNotifications.on('yes').subscribe(res =>{

        console.log('confirmed!');

      });

      this.isNotAcceptedObservable = this.localNotifications.on('no').subscribe(res =>{

        console.log('denied!');

      });

    });

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){

    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Notification received!',
      text: 'Haz recibido una invitación para ir a un lugar!',
      actions: [
        { id: 'yes',  title: 'Yes' , launch: true},
        { id: 'no',  title: 'No', launch: false}
      ],
      autoClear: true,
      foreground: true
    });

  }

  showNotification(){

    this.localNotifications.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Notification received!',
      text: 'Haz recibido una invitación para ir a un lugar!',
      actions: [
        { id: 'yes',  title: 'Yes' , launch: true},
        { id: 'no',  title: 'No', launch: false}
      ],
      autoClear: true,
      foreground: true
    });

  }

  ionViewWillLeave(){

    this.isAcceptedObservable.unsubscribe();
    this.isNotAcceptedObservable.unsubscribe();

  }

}
```

When I click on both buttons, nothing happens... also there are some important things for consider:

- Android platform version: android@6.4.0
- BackgroundMode plugin version (IMPORTANT, I'm using a different version of the most actual version, BackgroundMode actual plugin is incompatible with this version of android), version: 0.7.2
- LocalNotification plugin version: latest version or the penultimate (the results are the same).

Comment: Also i'm using cordova-android-support-gradle-release in both projects https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-support-gradle-release

Comment: Did you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your event name is not correct . Use

```
this.plt.ready().then(
            () => {
                this.localNotification.on('click').subscribe(
                    res => {}
                );
                this.localNotification.on('trigger').subscribe(
                    res => {}
                );
            }
        );
```

Comment: No - the OP is correct for named events this should work